# Jenkins report publisher with json

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, devops

Any idea about Jenkins extension for json result publisher? I'm using cypress to generate result which is generating result logs in .json format, I'm not sure about json report publisher nor got any concrete document. If someone knows it let me know.
I'm using Junit currently.

Comment: am not sure why that question was negated. i would also use JSON format with Jenkins (along with code coverage data from it).

Answer (score 1):

I believe that as of now there is no plugin that could help you to directly publish the JSON file content. But there is a workaround. once the JSON report is created, read the required data it using any suitable programming language like python or java and then display those data in the newly created html file. There is a plugin call html publisher plugin and with the help of that plugin, you will be able to display that html file.